# Directional derivative does not exist?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x) = ||x||$. Let $a \neq 0$ be arbitrary, and let $v = \frac{a}{||a||}$ be a unit vector in the direction of $a$. It makes intuitive sense that the rate of change of $f$ moving one unit in the direction of $a$ starting at $a$ should be $1$. However,
\begin{align*}
D_{v}f(a) &= \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(a + tv) - f(a)}{t} \\
&= \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{||a + t\frac{a}{||a||}|| - ||a||}{t} \\
&= \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{||a(1 + \frac{t}{||a||})|| - ||a||}{t} \\
&= \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{||a|||(1 + \frac{t}{||a||})| - ||a||}{t} \\
&= \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{|t|}{t}
\end{align*}
which does not exist. What am I missing here? In Ted Shifrin's book Multivariable Mathematics he asserts that this limit should be $1$, but doesn't explicitly show how to deal with the absolute value.

Thanks!

**Edit** The last step above is incorrect, since it asserts that $|||a|| + t| = ||a|| + |t|$ I think the right approach is to recognize that,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{|||a|| + t| - ||a||}{t}
\end{align*}
yields the indeterminate form $0/0$ at $t = 0$. For $t \in (-||a||, ||a||)$ we have $$||a|| + t > 0$$ so the absolute value function is differentiable on this interval, so we can proceed with l'hopital's rule:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{|||a|| + t| - ||a||}{t} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1}{1} = 1.
 = \end{align*} 
Alternatively, just recognizing that $||a|| + t > 0$ on $(-||a||, ||a||)$ seems to be enough to remove the absolute value.

Comment: Warning: You seem to be using the "rule" $|1+t| = 1 + |t|$. That is very incorrect.

Comment: Hi Prof. Shifrin! It's such an honor!! Your book / youtube series are fantastic! :) I've updated my answer -- does that look like the right approach to simplifying the absolute value? Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks :) No need for L’Hôpital. As the posted answer suggested, you only need to note that $|1+t| = 1+t$ whenever $t\ ge -1$, in particular for $t$ near $0$. Then finish with simple algebra.